# MultipartFilter in a non-Spring MVC application

Tags: java, spring, servlet-filters, multipartform-data

In our Java servlet (2.5) in Tomcat 6, we use Spring and Spring security 3 but no Spring MVC. We try to implement CSRF security, and therefor we added the `_csrf` token to all our forms. For file uploads we added the `org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter` to our `web.xml`, and also fixed the commons-fileupload dependency.

We can see that the request is parsed and wrapped, but spring security is also wrapping the request again, so we can't access the multipart data anymore, can we? I tried casting the request object to `MultipartHttpServletRequest` but it failed. All examples on the internet show how to access the file item in a Spring MVC controller. I'm a bit lost here.
[image: Wrappers wrapping each other]

Comment: Bonus question: I'm sure we use only servlet2.5, why is there a HttpServlet3RequestFactory present!?

Comment: Can you post your `web.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All those wrappers extend from the standard [`ServletRequestWrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequestWrapper.html) interface. Just cast to it, obtain the wrapped request via [`getRequest()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequestWrapper.html#getRequest()) method and test it instead.

You can even do it in a loop if it actually returned another `ServletRequestWrapper` implementation.

```
public static <R extends ServletRequest> R unwrap(ServletRequest request, Class<R> type) {
    ServletRequest current = request;

    while (!type.isInstance(current) && current instanceof ServletRequestWrapper) {
        current = ((ServletRequestWrapper) current).getRequest();
    }

    return type.isInstance(current) ? type.cast(current) : null;
}
```

Usage:

```
MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = unwrap(request, MultipartHttpServletRequest.class);
// ...
```

---

As to the bonus question: your webapp's runtime classpath contains somewhere Servlet 3.0+ API. If that's not the intent, then it's likely simply a dirty runtime classpath. Just cleanup it to get rid of Servlet 3.0+ libraries. Folders covered by the webapp's runtime classpath are a.o. WAR's `/WEB-INF/lib`, server's `/lib` and JRE's `/lib`.

Comment: Great, that works! Thanks. I think I found why there is servlet 3.0 present... My development machine is using Tomcat 7, which has the Servlet 3.0 API in the lib folder.

Comment: You're welcome. 
Spring would play nicer if it checked `version` in `web.xml` instead.

Answer (score 0):

although I like the way of how BalusC solved it better (with a while loop vs. recursion), I think it's worth mentioning that

```
import org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils;
...
WebUtils.getNativeRequest(request, MultipartHttpServletRequest.class);
```

does the same but just with a recursion, but in a well supported Lib-Class :)